# Can I use pywin32 WithEvents and to not preempt process?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I have a problem with win32com.client.WithEvents. I'm dispatching Excel, and its events. After that I encounter problem, that I cannot normally interact with Excel (e.g. save workbook), it seems like python had preempted the excel process.
Minimal example of my code:

What is really strange for me, this code works well with PyScripter internal engine, but doesn't work as I'd expect with remote engine, or in python console in PyCharm.

```
import win32com.client

class Events:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def OnWorkbookBeforeSave(self, workbook, saveAsUI, Cancel):
        print "before save"

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
event = win32com.client.WithEvents(excel, Events)
print "dispatched events"
wb.Save()
```

This code is intended to print "before save" every time document is saved. When I put it into interpreter it works well when I save workbook via python, but I cannot change the workbook content or save my workbook using my mouse and saving icon. However, when I use PyScripter internal engine it works.

Is there a way, that could be used in this case, so I could save my workbook via python and change its content like in normal interaction (using mouse and keyboard)? And not using PyScripter internal engine.